# Writing files to the Blobstore AppEngine and serving to client

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, blob, blobstore

**Objective:** Client sends String input to Server (App Engine). Server modifies input, creates a file with the output and serves it to Client. GWT project.

This is a scheme of my code (server side and client side), but **I don´t know how to serve the file to the client**. Whenever I try to enter any BlobStore imports in client side, I get errors at time of run (but not at time of build or compilation).

Writing files to Blobstore is marked as experimental (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore). Perhaps it is not working yet? Could you please help me with this issue? Even if it is not using Blobs, as long as Objective above is fulfilled. Thank you.

**ProjectServiceImpl.java**

```
public class ProjectServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements ProjectService 
{
    public String project(String input) throws IllegalArgumentException 
    {
        String output = doSomethingWith(input);
        FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
        AppEngineFile file = fileService.createNewBlobFile("text/plain");
        boolean lock = true;
        FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, lock);
        writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap("Hello world!".getBytes()));
        writeChannel.closeFinally();
        BlobKey blobKey = fileService.getBlobKey(file);
        BlobstoreService blobService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    }
}
```

**ProjectService.java**

```
public interface ProjectService extends RemoteService {
    String project(String name) throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

**ProjectServiceAsync.java**

```
public interface ProjectServiceAsync {
    void project(String input, AsyncCallback<String> callback)
            throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

**MyProject.java: Client side**

```
[...]
projectService.project(originalString, new AsyncCallback<String>() {
    [...]
    public void onSuccess(final String result) 
    {
        BlobstoreService blobService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use App Engine APIs - including the blobstore API - on the client side. APIs are only available to the App Engine app, not user Javascript. To serve up a blob, follow the instructions [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html#Serving_a_Blob).

Comment: Thanks Nick! So just adding the Serve.java in the link you provided and passing to that class the correct blobKey would be enough? There is no need to add any Blob code to MyProject.java? Do I need my server-side classes to extend HttpServlet instead of RemoteService, as in the example in the link? Thanks!

Comment: @user411103 Write a servlet like the one in the demo; how it works depends on how you want to serve your blobs. Your servlet does need to extend HttpServlet.